# Get average and max in 1 minute intervals T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that extracts the number of records in 1 minute intervals. I want to compare the average vs last value.

I only get he total which is the count(1) and its valid. The average and the maximum is always returning as 1 which is not accurate.

Is there something that I am missing in this SQL?

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(timestamp, 'hh:mm') AS tm, 
    AVG(1) AS avgOccurances, 
    MAX(1) AS maxocc, 
    COUNT(1) AS total 
FROM   
    [history] 
WHERE  
    timestamp BETWEEN '2018-04-16 14:00:00.707' AND '2018-04-18 15:00:00.707' 
    AND result = 'F' 
GROUP BY 
    FORMAT(timestamp, 'hh:mm') 
ORDER BY 
    tm ASC
```

Result

```
01:00   1   1   13
01:01   1   1   10
01:02   1   1   11
01:03   1   1    7
01:04   1   1   13
01:05   1   1    7
01:06   1   1   14
01:07   1   1   11
01:08   1   1   12
01:09   1   1   10
01:10   1   1    5
01:11   1   1    6
01:12   1   1    8
01:13   1   1   13
01:14   1   1    9
01:15   1   1    8
01:16   1   1    2
01:17   1   1   10
01:18   1   1    9
01:19   1   1   13
01:20   1   1    9
01:21   1   1    8
01:22   1   1   14
01:23   1   1   10
```

Comment: Well...you are taking the average of the literal 1. It will ALWAYS be 1. What do you want the average of? Same with MAX. It is a literal. And be careful naming columns, you should avoid using reserved words as column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below assumes each row should have the following:

- Count per minute
- Count per minute for the previous minute
- Count for the minute with the most occurrences

If that's incorrect just let me know. Here's the query:

```
WITH countbyminute AS (
  SELECT
    FORMAT(timestamp, 'hh:mm') AS tm,
    COUNT(*) AS occurences
  FROM history
  GROUP BY FORMAT(timestamp, 'hh:mm')
)
SELECT
  tm,
  occurrences,
  LAG(occurrences) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) AS priorocc,
  MAX(occurrences) OVER () AS maxocc
FROM countbyminute
ORDER BY tm;
```

And I'd suggest using `HH:mm` as the format string, which will rerurn the hours using a 24-hour clock (1:00PM as 13:00).

Comment: Is there a way, i can compare average of 7 instances. for eg. get average of  records for the  same minute for last 7 days?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer that. I'm sure it's doable, but it's a *lot* more involved and I don't have SQL Server at home or work (the answer above is off the top of my head from recent SQL Server experience). I'd suggest re-posting the question with the new requirement; there are a lot of folks who could answer it. Make sure the question is very specific. Your question above showed the output really well but it didn't show the input or the table structure. Including those will help get a good answer. Good luck!